# Можно ли отправить json файл без библиотек на сервер?

Tags: javascript, node.js, веб-программирование, express

Есть локальный сервер на node.js, использую express. Хочу узнать можно ли отправить json на сервер без каких либо библиотек(например JQuery), только с помощью javascript?

Comment: С помощью [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) или [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Comment: Спасибо, я нашёл там то что искал)